# How to get specific name inside child firebase database into recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I kinda confused, how to get specific name inside child key, i only know set recyclerview, but don't know how to get grandprice set to TextView, because grandprice is inside another child, my database down below.

[image: database Image]

key is CardView and grandprice is TextView.

this is my code

```
//RecyclerView
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recommeneded);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
//mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(HomeActivity.this));
final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.myDataLoaderProgressBar);
mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

final int position = 0;
recommended = new ArrayList<>();
mAdapter = new InvoiceAdapter(getActivity(), recommended);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(HomeActivity.this);

rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
usersRef = rootRef.child("order");
uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

mDBListener = usersRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        recommended.clear();

        for (DataSnapshot invoiceSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            InvoiceModels upload = invoiceSnapshot.getValue(InvoiceModels.class);
            upload.setKey(invoiceSnapshot.getKey());
            recommended.add(position, upload);
            
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
//RecyclerView
```

my adapter

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        InvoiceModels currentProduct = recomended.get(position);

        //holder.totalPrice.setText(currentProduct.getTotalPrice());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, currentProduct.getTotalPrice(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recomended.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView totalPrice;

        public RelativeLayout relativelayout;


        public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            totalPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);

            relativelayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);


        }

    }
```

Thank for helping, sincerely,
AL.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No, not yet! but I'll check/comment when I solved the issue, thanks

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the `id` of that `inv-details`. Next you can call the data inside it. You can try this.

```
recommended.clear();
//At here you get the id first.
final String keyOfChild = dataSnapshot.getKey();
usersRef.child(uid).child(keyOfChild).child("inv-details").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

   InvoiceModels upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(InvoiceModels.class);
   upload.setKey(invoiceSnapshot.getKey());
   recommended.add(position, upload);

   mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```